# reference a compound key in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I want to add a foreign key which reference the column in itself

```
FOREIGN KEY ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID NOT NULL REFERENCES
ACCREDITATION_BODY_LOOK_UP(ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID),
```

and the SQL in the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE  "COURSE_ACCREDITED" 
      ("COURSE_ID" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"DATE_OBTAINED" VARCHAR2(50), 
 PRIMARY KEY ("COURSE_ID", "ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID", "DATE_OBTAINED") ENABLE)
```

When I add this foreign key, it appears ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

What is the problem?

Comment: Post the definition of the `accreditation_body_look_up` table.  The error indicates that `accreditation_body_id` is not the primary key of that table.

Comment: Did you read the error message? A foreign key needs to reference a unique key or primary key in the referenced table -- which can be the same table.

Comment: Your question title and introduction don't your SQL. You are apparently adding a single column foreign key which references a different table. So you should stop wasting everybody's time and explain what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Does ACCREDITATION_BODY_LOOK_UP have primary key (or unique key)?

```
select constraint_name, constraint_type
from user_constraints
where table_name = 'ACCREDITATION_BODY_LOOK_UP'
and constraint_type in ('P', 'U');
```

If yes, what are its columns?  You need to reference all those columns in the same order when you add a foreign key to a dependent table.

```
select column_name, position
from user_cons_columns
where table_name = 'ACCREDITATION_BODY_LOOK_UP'
and constraint_name = '<< constraint from previous query >>';
```

If no, then you need to create a primary key on that table before you can reference it in a foreign key.

```
alter table ACCREDITATION_BODY_LOOK_UP
    add constraint ACCR_BODY_LKUP_PK primary key (ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID);
```

Answer (score -1):

This means that the child table has values which are not found in the parent table.

You just need to delete these orphaned values or define the foreign key with "novalidate" which skips checking the integrity between the child and parent tables.

CORRECTION:  THIS ADDRESS A DIFFERENT PK/FK ERROR

ORA-02270 is because you're trying to create a foreign key and the key is not referencing a primary key or column with a unique constraint.

Comment: It does not. It means that it can't make the foreign key because there's "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list".