# ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

Tags: oracle

I have a table, and the structure is

```
CREATE TABLE  "COURSE_ACCREDITED" 
("COURSE_ID" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID" VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
"DATE_OBTAINED" VARCHAR2(50), 
 PRIMARY KEY ("COURSE_ID", "ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID", "DATE_OBTAINED") ENABLE, 
 CONSTRAINT "COURSE_ACCREDITED_CON" FOREIGN KEY ("COURSE_ID")
  REFERENCES  "COURSE" ("COURSE_ID") ENABLE)
```

When I add a constrain

```
alter table "COURSE_ACCREDITED" add constraint
"COURSE_ACCREDITED_CON2" foreign key ("ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID") references "COURSE_ACCREDITED"    ("ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID")
```

It appears  ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list

What is the problem?

Comment: The error says it all. You don't have any index where `ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID` is the first column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [reference a compound key in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16289040/reference-a-compound-key-in-oracle)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by adding a foreign key reference to a the same column in the table? Are you actually looking to add a unique index?

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. If you aren't getting answer, [improve the original question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a [composite (or compound) key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) by making this primary:

```
("COURSE_ID", "ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID", "DATE_OBTAINED")
```

and then, you try to make `ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID` a foreign key, referencing to the same column on the same table. I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but anyway, It's **not** the correct way to do it.

In my opinion, ***Reason is:***   `ACCREDITATION_BODY_ID` must be a primary key in order to be referenced as a foreign key, but that's not the case here. Your table's constraint is a **compound key**, and you need to reference **all** the columns in the foreign key statement. (fix me if I'm wrong)

Try reference all the compound key columns in the foreign key statement. That may solve your problem.

By the way, referencing a primary key as a foreign key in the same table didn't make any sense to me (maybe i'm missing something but still..). I'd consider changing the design.